# QtDataVisualization "meshing" Q3Dscatter

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, data-visualization, point-clouds

I would like to be able to *mesh* a [Q3DScatter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/q3dscatter.html) (having it look like a [Q3DSurface](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/q3dsurface.html)), or at least drawing lines between the  points.

I have not found anything like this in the docs or in the examples, is there a simple way to do it, or will I have to create my own visualization ?

Comment: Could use vtk to draw calculate and draw the Visualization